# Unable to post status message on Twitter using TwitterHelper

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter

I want to let the users to my website post some messages to their Twitter Account. For this, I am using TwitterHelper, a JS Twitter API Wrapper. But I am unable to post any status messages. Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Code snippet :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TwitterHelper.js"></script>

// function to post status message to twitter account
function postOnTwitter(shortURL){
    var twitterClient;

    twitterClient = new TwitterHelper('letsTripp', '******', null, 'twitter');
    twitterClient.statuses.update(null, null, null, 'json', 'Testing Trippin', null, null);
}
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library, but it sure looks like you are sending a user name and password. That is basic authentication, which no longer works for Twitter. You now have to user OAuth authentication. I use PHP Twitter, so I don't know of a good OAuth library for JS. You can look here:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#javascript